# Insert text after specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to insert a `div` after a certain amount of characters in a paragraph of text?

If I have a `div` full of text, like so:

```
<div class="content">
Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis.
</div>
```

And I want to insert a `div` after the 13th character:

```
Vivamus luctu<div>s urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis
```

Can I do this with jQuery/Javascript?

I am receiving the bounds for where I want to insert a `div` from `getSelection().extentOffset` which results in a number, say `13` which is where I want to insert the `div`.

I was able to get this to partially work, like so:

```
$("div").on("mouseup", function () {
    var start = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
    var end = window.getSelection().extentOffset;
    console.log(start + ", " + end);
    console.log($(".content").text().substring(start, end));
    $('.output').html($('.content').html().substring(0, start) + '<span class="highlight">' + $('.content').html().substring(start, end) + "</span>" + $('.content').html().substring(end));
});
```

But that replaces the entire text when the bounds change, meaning that there can't be more than one section wrapped in a `div`.

Comment: `"Vivamus luctu<div>s urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis" isn't valid.` : a div must be closed.

Comment: Obviously. What I would do is use the same method and put a closing `div` at the end bound.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a complex problem specially if you trying to achieve cross browser functionality. I recommend using this library [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/)
Also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454152/cross-browser-selection-range-library) for an example usage

Comment: Luckily, I don't need cross browser compatibility. Just Safari.

Comment: And I'm looking at Rangy, but I need to be able to detect if the text that is being highlighted is already highlighted, and if it is, delete the current highlight, and add in a new one that combines both parts. Do you know if Rangy can do that?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339857/how-to-know-if-selected-text-is-inside-a-specific-div

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, that only returns true if the entire selection is JUST the previous selection. I need to be able to detect if any part of the currently selected text includes a highlighted section.

Comment: You can probably use https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange#getNodes%28%5BArray_nodeTypes%5B,_Function_filter%5D%5D%29

Comment: If you have the time, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(".content").contents()` to get the text-DOM-Nodes and can replace them with that part you want, just look if the nodeType is what you want.

http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: after reading twice, i think i misunderstood your question. What is the goal you want to reach? make some selected text being put into somewhere else or just having it wrapped in that div? maybe i can help you with it anyway ;)