# javascript pattern to determine when someone is selecting text on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to determine if someone has selected text on a page.

There are two ways I can see to select text. Double-click on it (which automatically selects the text) or click-and-drag to select text.

- How would I fire an event on double-click?
- How would I fire an event when someone selects text?

jQuery is preferred

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731328/on-text-highlight-event

Comment: Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454152/cross-browser-selection-range-library

Answer (score 0):

for Double click see :  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp

for selected text see : [Selected text event trigger in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In IE and WebKit browsers, there is a `selectionchange` event that fires on document nodes which sounds like what you want:

```
document.onselectionchange = function() {
    console.log("Selection changed!");
};
```

Otherwise, you'll need to detect mouse and key events and inspect the selection object when they fire.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035122/96100
- [Issue in Mozilla's issue tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571294)